# Server 2012 Linked Server From An Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, spn

I have 3 SQL Server 2012 Instances, 2 on *SiteA* on the same server *SiteAServer*.  I have 1 on *SiteB* on server *SiteBServer*.

```
SiteADefaultInstance, SiteASecondInstance

SiteBDefaultInstance
```

- *SiteBDefaultInstance* can create a linked server to
  *SiteADefaultInstance* and *SiteASecondInstance*.
- *SiteADefaultInstance* can create a linked server to
  *SiteBDefaultInstance*.
- *SiteASecondInstance* CANNOT create a linked server to
  *SiteBDefaultInstance*.

I get the error

> "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"

I am setting the security to be made using the current context.

I have ran `setSPN` for *SiteAServer* and *SiteBServer*.  You don't have to change the commands if you have more than one instance do you?
I am in the role sysadmin.

I have never experienced where it only worked one way before.  Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Definitely an issue with Kerberos. "You don't have to change the commands if you have more than one instance do you?" it's a PER SERVICE setup, so yes you need to change the values per service.

Comment: `setspn -U -A MSSQLSvc/SiteAServer:1433 user` and `setspn -U -A MSSQLSvc/SiteBServer:1433 user` are the commands I ran.  What is the correct way to specify the instance?  `setspn -U -A MSSQLSvc/SiteAServer\SiteASecondInstance:1433 user`?

Comment: Have you tried the SQL Server Kerberos Configuration Manager? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: @spaghettidba beat me to it! Kerberos Config Manager is amazing, and I highly recommend it to customers when dealing with Kerberos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments were very useful in leading to the solution.  After running SQL Server Kerberos Configuration Manager I saw that while the first was on 1433 for SiteADefaultInstance and the second instance of the database was listening on a dynamic port for SiteASecondInstance.

Went into SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SiteASecondInstance > TCP/IP and change IPALL TcpPort to a different port, say 9999.

```
SetSPN -s "MSSQLSvc/SiteAServer:9999" "user"
```

After this could create a linked server.

Comment: The 'most correct' way to fix this is to grant the service account the ability to register its own SPNs. That way you never have any hard-coded ports.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx